# How can I change my custom cell background when pressing a button?

Tags: swift, button, uicollectionviewcell, background-color

I have a CollectionView and a Button inside of an UIView. The purpose of the button is change the theme of the app, and I can change all colors, except for the backgroundColor of a nameContainerView on my TatodexCell (a custom cell).

I can't figure out how to access that property, and then, change the color I want.

> THE FOLLOWING CODE IS LOCATED ON MY TatodexController FILE

**My button property is:**

```
    let buttonChangeTheme: UIButton? = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Change to blue theme", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(themeButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.layer.borderWidth = 3
    button.layer.borderColor = Colors.mainBlack?.cgColor
    button.backgroundColor = Colors.darkBlue
    button.tintColor = Colors.mainWhite
   return button
}()
```

**My button-func is this one:**

```
    @objc func themeButtonClicked() {
    
    clickCheck = !clickCheck
    
    if clickCheck {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colors.lightBlue
        collectionViewPokemon?.backgroundColor           = Colors.darkBlue
        buttonChangeTheme?.backgroundColor               = Colors.darkRed
        buttonChangeTheme?.setTitle("Return to red theme", for: .normal)
        }
    else {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colors.lightRed
        collectionViewPokemon?.backgroundColor           = Colors.darkRed
        buttonChangeTheme?.backgroundColor               = Colors.darkBlue
        buttonChangeTheme?.setTitle("Change to blue theme", for: .normal)
    }
}
```

> THE FOLLOWING CODE IS LOCATED ON MY TatodexCell FILE

**The nameContainerView I wanna modify it's bg color is:**

```
 lazy var nameContainerView: UIView = {
    
   let nameView              = UIView()
    nameView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightRed
    nameView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.center(inView: nameView)
    return nameView
}()
```

My goal is to change `nameView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightRed` to `nameView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightBlue`, but I can't access that property.

I would really appreciate any help or advice. Perhaps the solution is hiding in plain sight, but I've tried many ways and none of them worked. Let me know if another chunk of code is needed to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the `tintColorDidChange()` method in your custom collection view cell, and in that method, you set the cell's background color to the tint color, then when you change the owning UICollectionView's tint color, the cells's `tintColorDidChange()` methods will fire and you'll see the change.

Comment: I added this method on my custom collectionViewCell  `override func tintColorDidChange() {
        nameContainerView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightBlue
    }`, and then called it on my `themeButtonClicked ` function, but it isn't working